# Remove GRUB from macOS Catalina

Tags: startup, dual-boot, grub

So I installed Ubuntu on an external disk via my MacBook Pro 2016 with a USB flash. Now whenever I try installing another Linux distro such as Pop_OS I see the GRUB loader complaining about a bunch of stuff and I also had to change my booting disk to my macOS Catalina so I understand that GRUB is the main loader rather than the default macOS one. Is there a way for me to completely remove GRUB without having to reinstall macOS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Ubuntu, GRUB files are stored in the `EFI/BOOT` and `EFI/ubuntu` folders in the hidden `EFI` partition. Apply the following steps to remove the GRUB files.

1. Enter the following command to determine the identifier for the hidden EFI partition on the external drive.

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   For this example, I will assume the identifier is `disk2s1`. In the following steps, make the appropriate substitutions.
2. To mount the volume stored in the `EFI` partition, enter the following command.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount disk2s1
   ```

   Note the volume name given in the output of this command. For this example, I will assume the volume name is `EFI`. In the following steps, make the appropriate substitutions.
3. Use the Finder application to view the folders in the `EFI` folder of the `EFI` volume (device). See image below.

   [image]
4. Move the folders `BOOT` and `ubuntu` to the trash.
5. Empty the trash.
6. Enter the following command to unmount the `EFI` volume (device).

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk2s1
   ```

Comment: And this wouldn't affect my macOS installation, correct? I want to be sure that I will be able to boot again without having to reinstall.

Comment: macOS does not use any files stored in this volume to boot. So, this wouldn't affect your macOS installation.

Comment: Worked fine on my Macbook Air (Intel)