# Attempt to fix macOS startup volume after dual-boot Linux partition removal

Tags: hard-drive, partition, startup, unix, dual-boot

I have attempted to install Linux on my **MacBook Pro 15"** alongside macOS (**Catalina**) for a team project.

Since I needed the space reserved for the Linux partition back, I have decided to remove it through the standard `disk utility.App` procedure.

[image: disk3]

[image: disk4]

As you can see from the sidebar view, the two partitions reserved for Linux were respectively:

1. `disk0s3`: for swap memory (16 GB), formatted as **MS-DOS FAT**
2. `disk0s4`: (350 GB) Volume for the OS

There's also an SD card, but it is used as an external support

Firstly, I foolishly removed (with `-`) the SWAP partition (disk0s3 volume); Then I noticed that `disk0s4` was not a Container disk1 "child" anymore.

To better understand what was going on, I ran `diskutil list`, whose output was

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical)
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:  GUID_partition_scheme                   +1 TB           disk0
    1:      EFI EFI                             209.7 MB        disk0s1
    2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF     635.5 GB        disk0s2
    3:  Microsoft Basic Data Untitled           350.4 GB        disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized)
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:  APFS Container Scheme -                 +633.5 GB       disk1
                              Physical Store disk   disk0s2
    1:      APFS Volume macOS - Dati            380.9 GB        disk1s1
    2:      APFS Volume Preboot                 81.4  MB        disk1s2
    3:      APFS Volume Recovery                530.0 MB        disk1s3
    4:      APFS Volume macOS                   11.3  GB        disk1s4
    5:      APFS Volume VM                      1.1   GB        disk1s5

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical)
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:  FDisk_partition_scheme                  +256.1 GB       disk2
    0:          Windows_NFTS                    +256.1 GB       disk2s1
```

[image: run diskutil list]

Then the laptop suddenly died (I guess the battery was low).

Currently, As I turn it on, it just displays the grub2 menu.
Also, By restarting it and by keeping pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I can only choose "EFI boot" and by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it returns to the initial stage (grub2 menu).

Therefore, I made the laptop go into recovery mode through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

At first, by simply running the terminal command `diskutil list` no volumes were listed under `disk0`, nor under `disk1` (Differently from what happened in [this case](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388159/attempted-to-fix-macos-startup-volume-after-failed-dual-boot-linux-install-but)) as it seemed it did not recognise the SSD anymore (which, btw is a Samsung SSD 970 Evo Plus, size 1 TB).

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:  GUID_partition_scheme                   +1 TB           disk0
    1:      Apple_HFS OS X Base System          2.0 GB          disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +5.2 MB         disk1
    
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk2
    
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk3
    
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk5
    
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk6
    
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk7
    
/dev/disk8 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk8
    
/dev/disk9 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk9
    
/dev/disk10 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk10
    
/dev/disk11 (disk image):
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk11
    
/dev/disk12 (disk image):
#:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
#:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
0:          Untitled                        +524.3 KB       disk13

/dev/disk14 (internal, physical)
    #:      TYPE NAME                           SIZE            IDENTIFIER
    0:  FDisk_partition_scheme                  +256.1 GB       disk14
    0:          Windows_NFTS Pippo              +256.1 GB       disk14s1
```

also, by running `gpt -r show disk0` the output was

```
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk0
    start       size        index       contents
        0           1                   PMBR
        1           1                   Pri GPT header
        2          32                   Pri GPT table
        34          6                   
        40    3927784           1       GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   4189935         32                   Sec GPT table
   4189967          1                   Sec GPT header
```

At a later time, after restarting the computer, entering recovery mode, I noticed a change in the interface, almost as if it had been updated. In fact, running the same commands, I got respectively

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF ⁨⁩              633.5 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         16.1 GB    -
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨UNTITLED⁩                350.4 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +3.2 GB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨macOS Base System⁩       2.9 GB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk12
   1:               Windows_NTFS ⁨Pippo                  256.1 GB   disk12s1

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk21
```

whereas, by running again `gpt -r show disk0`

```
-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1237327656      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  1237737296    31357104         
  1269094400   684429312      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1953523712        1423         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Lastly, in the start screen, 'Install an OS' no longer appears, but rather 'Install Monterey'.

Is there any way to solve this trouble and start back macOS?

Comment: This is a nicely presented question. However, it is better to text the text output of a command line console, rather than a screenshot. This is because an image is not text searchable. Paste the command output and block code format the text using (`\`\`\``... [code] ... `\`\`\``).

Comment: You posted an image of the output from `diskutil list` while booted to Recovery. I think the image does not show the entire output. Could you post the output from `diskutil list internal` while booted to Recovery? While text is better than an image as suggested by @Greenonline, most users do not know how to do this from Recovery. So, in this case, posting an image would be sufficient.

Comment: Wipe the laptop, reinstall macOS, restore your backup.  That would seem to be the easiest.

Comment: I disagree. Marc's solution seems like cumbersome way to correct the value of a 16 byte integer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have posted the output you asked for, and adapted the photo’s content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This answer works with macOS. In other words, Sierra (macOS 10.12) through Sonoma (macOS 14).**

Many of the past answers, posted here at Ask Different to this type of question, used the `gpt` command to fix the GUID Partition Table (GPT). However, since this is no longer possible with the newer releases of macOS, this answer will use the third party `gdisk` command instead. This command will be downloaded from the SourceForge project [GPT fdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) and will be automatically removed when the Mac is restarted.

1. Boot to Recovery. Use the command below to confirm the (product) version of macOS is 10.12 or newer.

   ```
   sw_vers
   ```
2. Get the `gdisk` command. Enter the commands given below. The first command downloads a script which be used to get `gdisk`. The second command executes this script. If you do not wish to trust this script, then you can substitute the commands given in the section below titled *"Getting `gdisk` Without Using a Script"*.

   ```
   curl -o /tmp/get-gdisk https://maclinks.publicvm.com/get-gdisk
   bash /tmp/get-gdisk
   ```
3. Fix the GPT. Enter the command below to get the identifier for the drive with the GPT that needs repair.

   ```
   diskutil list internal
   ```

   Enter the command below. If your identifier is not `disk0`, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   /tmp/gdisk /dev/disk0
   ```

   The `gdisk` command is interactive. The input can be taken from the first column of the table given below.

   | Entry | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `p` | command | Print the partition table |
   | `s` | command | Sort partitions |
   | `d` | command | Delete a partition |
   | `3` | parameter | Partition number |
   | `t` | command | Change a partition's type code |
   | `2` | parameter | Partition number |
   | `af0a` | parameter | Hex code for APFS type partitions |
   | `p` | command | Print the partition table |
   | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit |
   | `y` | parameter | Confirm to proceed |
4. Restart the Mac to macOS.
5. Recover the free space. Enter the command below to get the identifier for the `Apple_APFS` container.

   ```
   diskutil list internal
   ```

   Enter the command below. If your identifier is not `disk0s2`, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
   ```

You are finished.

---

### Getting `gdisk` Without Using a Script

```
cd /tmp
rm -rf gdisk.files gdisk
mkdir gdisk.files
cd gdisk.files
curl -L -o gdisk.pkg https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.9/gdisk-binaries/gdisk-1.0.9.pkg
pkgutil --expand gdisk.pkg gdisk
tar xvf gdisk/Payload ./usr/local/bin/gdisk
mv usr/local/bin/gdisk ..
cd ..
rm -r gdisk.files
cd ~
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine! Since I no longer need the `EFI` partition, I would also remove the grub loader at boot. Based on your answer in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402858/remove-grub-from-macos-catalina), do I need to mount `disk0s1`, move BOOT and Ubuntu dirs to the trash and unmount the `EFI` volume?

Comment: TylerDuren: Yes, provided the Linux was Ubuntu. Grub and other Linux boot files are usually stored in `disk0s1`.